# XSL query for KeePass (Specific Entry)

Tags: xml, xslt

My target is to extract specific keys out of KeyPass(2.x) xml format by xsl.

The KeyPass XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<KeePassFile>
    <Meta>
        <Generator>KeePass</Generator>
    </Meta>
    <Root>
        <Group>
            <UUID>NqDrFtUxs0SiwVPehBpONg==</UUID>
            <Name>ExampleDatabase</Name>
            <Entry>
                <String>
                    <Key>Notes</Key>
                    <Value>Notes</Value>
                </String>
                <String>
                    <Key>Password</Key>
                    <Value ProtectInMemory="True">Password</Value>
                </String>
                <String>
                    <Key>Title</Key>
                    <Value>Sample Entry</Value>
                </String>
                <String>
                    <Key>URL</Key>
                    <Value>http://keepass.info/</Value>
                </String>
                <String>
                    <Key>UserName</Key>
                    <Value>User Name</Value>
                </String>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <String>
                    <Key>Password</Key>
                    <Value ProtectInMemory="True">12345</Value>
                </String>
                <String>
                    <Key>Title</Key>
                    <Value>Sample Entry #2</Value>
                </String>
                <String>
                    <Key>URL</Key>
                    <Value>http://keepass.info/help/kb/testform.html</Value>
                </String>
                <String>
                    <Key>UserName</Key>
                    <Value>Michael321</Value>
                </String>
            </Entry>
            <Group>
                <UUID>mec/n7Hkf0uZMDMrZyaO7A==</UUID>
                <Name>General</Name>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <UUID>mBKJFmgV6UOQQmXlmhZt/A==</UUID>
                <Name>Windows</Name>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <UUID>CKbqJW0RwUKdUT/go0EnJg==</UUID>
                <Name>Network</Name>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <UUID>B6yKdAooSkOj6+uvrGDURQ==</UUID>
                <Name>Internet</Name>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <UUID>4IG7YyeaY0yHbnuUtJMx5A==</UUID>
                <Name>eMail</Name>
                <Entry>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Notes</Key>
                        <Value>Some Note</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Password</Key>
                        <Value ProtectInMemory="True">1.Os0mnyE6ESeL1yGnTsX6</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                        <Value>Entry1</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>URL</Key>
                        <Value />
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>UserName</Key>
                        <Value>Some@Email.com</Value>
                    </String>
                    <History>
                        <Entry>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Notes</Key>
                                <Value>Some Note</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Password</Key>
                                <Value ProtectInMemory="True">Os0mnyE6ESeL1yGnTsX6</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Title</Key>
                                <Value>Entry1</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>URL</Key>
                                <Value />
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>UserName</Key>
                                <Value>FirsteMail@Adress.com</Value>
                            </String>
                        </Entry>
                    </History>
                </Entry>
                <Entry>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Notes</Key>
                        <Value>Some Note</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Password</Key>
                        <Value ProtectInMemory="True">2.RlYOCgZDirnjbjcu8Td2</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                        <Value>Entry2</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>URL</Key>
                        <Value />
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>UserName</Key>
                        <Value>SecondeMail@Adress.com</Value>
                    </String>
                    <History>
                        <Entry>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Notes</Key>
                                <Value>Login für den Plesk Server.</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Password</Key>
                                <Value ProtectInMemory="True">RlYOCgZDirnjbjcu8Td2</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Title</Key>
                                <Value>Entry2</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>URL</Key>
                                <Value />
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>UserName</Key>
                                <Value>Adress@Bla.com</Value>
                            </String>
                        </Entry>
                    </History>
                </Entry>
                <Entry>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Notes</Key>
                        <Value>Some Note</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Password</Key>
                        <Value ProtectInMemory="True">3.RzJsbTeK29MS1GnUiTlb</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                        <Value>Entry3</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>URL</Key>
                        <Value />
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>UserName</Key>
                        <Value>ThirdeMail@Adress.com</Value>
                    </String>
                    <History>
                        <Entry>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Notes</Key>
                                <Value>Some Note</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Password</Key>
                                <Value ProtectInMemory="True">RzJsbTeK29MS1GnUiTlb</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Title</Key>
                                <Value>Entry3</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>URL</Key>
                                <Value />
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>UserName</Key>
                                <Value>ThirdeMail@Adress.com</Value>
                            </String>
                        </Entry>
                    </History>
                </Entry>
                <Entry>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Notes</Key>
                        <Value>Some Note</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Password</Key>
                        <Value ProtectInMemory="True">4.8BONlQkfKRHpPdTL3luh</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                        <Value>Entry4</Value>
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>URL</Key>
                        <Value />
                    </String>
                    <String>
                        <Key>UserName</Key>
                        <Value>eMail@Adress.com</Value>
                    </String>
                    <History>
                        <Entry>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Notes</Key>
                                <Value>Some Note</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Password</Key>
                                <Value ProtectInMemory="True">8BONlQkfKRHpPdTL3luh</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>Title</Key>
                                <Value>Entry4</Value>
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>URL</Key>
                                <Value />
                            </String>
                            <String>
                                <Key>UserName</Key>
                                <Value>eMail@Adress.com</Value>
                            </String>
                        </Entry>
                    </History>
                </Entry>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <UUID>A/OASMueGE+ZBzEpvrTjow==</UUID>
                <Name>Homebanking</Name>
            </Group>
        </Group>
        <DeletedObjects />
    </Root>
</KeePassFile>
```

I want to access the value of a single 'Value' tag. So for example the Value of the Group eMail in the Kategory Title or Password. The value would then be (eMail/Title:) 'Entry1'. I just need the xsl to gather the information of the KeePass.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the `UserName` key, which occurs four times in that `Group`, once in each child `Entry`. In that case you need to select the third `Entry` to obtain the third email. In your code you can achieve that using a positional predicate to `Entry`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Entry[3]/String">
    <xsl:if test="Key='UserName'">
        <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: "KeePass NqDrFtUxs0SiwVPehBpONg== ExampleDatabase Notes Notes Password Password Title Sample Entry URL ht[...]". The code snippet returns all data. How can I filter the result to a single value. Like "KeePassFile/Root/Group/Group/Entry/String" where the second group is i.e. 'eMail' and the Key 'UserName'. The result would be 'Some@Email.com'

Comment: Please edit your question and describe exactly what you need using a complete code example. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="KeePassFile/Root/Group/Group[child::Name='eMail']/Entry[1]/String[Key='UserName']">
<td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
</xsl:for-each>
```